# Gradient is zero on the preimage of a negligible set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $f\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R^n}$ is open, and $E\subset\mathbb{R}$ a negligible Borel subset, i.e. $\mathcal{L}^1(E)=0$.

> Is it always the case that $Df\equiv 0$ a.e. on $f^{-1}(E)$?

The same result when $E$ is a singleton is well-known.

I need this as a lemma to prove that if $h:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz then $h\circ f\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ (assuming $\Omega$ bounded or
$h(0)=0$) and $\nabla(h\circ f)=(h' \circ f)\nabla f$, which I am quite confident to be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ be a bounded open set comfortably distant from the origin and define $f : \Omega \to \mathbb R^2$ by $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{|x|}$. The image of $f$ lies on the unit sphere, hence $\mathcal L^2(f(\Omega)) = 0$.

The differential $Df$ is rather easily computed and seen to be nonzero on $\Omega$.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question focusing on the scalar case. Do you know any reference for the fact that $h\circ f\in W^{1,1}$?

Comment: A function $g \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ if and only if (a representative of) $g$ is absolutely continuous on almost every line segment parallel to the axes and $g$, $\nabla g$ are both in $L^1$. Composition with a Lipschitz function preserves this property.

Comment: Your comment also answers the question (better late than never). Actually it suffices that $E$ has empty "essential" interior, i.e. that $\mathcal{L}^1(U\setminus E)>0$ for every nonempty open set $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.